# Jquery Validate 1.9 with tabs

Tags: jquery-validate

I have created 2 examples, one with Jquery Validate 1.9 and other with Jquery Validate 1.6. I have one form in which I have created tabs with the help of Jquery UI. I want that when user click a button all tabs should be validated. Jquery Validate 1.6 does this but Jquery validate 1.9 only validate current selected/visible tab. To highlight error tabs I am using some code I found on net. This code is working with 1.6 but not working with 1.9.

Please refer following links for example.

http://micmindia.com/JqueryValidate1.6/JqueryUIValidate1.6WithTabs.html

http://micmindia.com/JqueryValidate1.9/JqueryUIValidate1.9WithTabs.html

Answer:
Author of the library has helped in solving the problem

```
  $("#validatetabs").validate({
    ignore: [],                //This has to be addedd
        highlight: function (input) {
            $(input).addClass("ui-state-error");
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            //return true;
        },
        invalidHandler:.....
```

the above change has been described in this change log
 ://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/21707129666012f6b0bc60622eb3bcb9f87daa04

Comment: Please do not post the solution within your question.  Please post the answer below in the answers section and accept it.